# Drop Down Search by Category in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently trying to implement a simple drop-down search by category feature. However, it seems like I am running into some issues—my search functions seem not to be working. The search function in my model is this:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_one_attached :image

    #validates :image, attached: true, content_type: %w(image/jpg image/jpeg image/png)

    def self.search(search)
        if search
            images = Image.all
            images = Image.where(meal_category: search[:":meal_category"][","])
            return images
        else
            Image.all
        end
    end
```

The forms looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag(images_path, method: "get") do %>
                  <select name= image[:thing], class=“form-control”>
                    <option value=“None”>Meal Category</option>
                    <option value=“Breakfast”>Breakfast</option>
                    <option value=“Lunch/Dinner”>Lunch/Dinner</option>
                    <option value=“Dessert”>Dessert</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <%end%>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index, :submit]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /images
  # GET /images.json
  def index
    @images = Image.search(params[:thing])
  end
```

and finally, my routes are configured as such:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :images
  devise_for :users
  get '/upload', to: 'images#new'
  root 'images#index'
  get "/search", to: "images#search"
  get '/@:username', to: 'users#show', as: :profile
  resources :images, only: [:index, :show, :create]

  delete 'images/:id(.:format)', :to => 'images#destroy'
end
```

It seems as though my parameters are not being passed through properly. I tried playing around with the parameters, but I failed to identify the problem. Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

some subtle changes, can you see if this works more like you'd expect:

**form**

```
<%= form_tag(images_path, method: "get") do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:thing, options_for_select(@select_options)) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<%end%>
```

**controller**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index, :submit]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /images
  # GET /images.json
  def index
    @select_options = {
      "None": "Meal Category", 
      "Breakfast": “Breakfast”,
      "Lunch/Dinner": “Lunch/Dinner”,
      "Dessert": “Dessert”
    }
    @images = Image.all
    @images = @images.search(params[:thing]) if params[:thing] && params[:thing] != "None"
  end
```

**class**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :image

  #validates :image, attached: true, content_type: %w(image/jpg image/jpeg image/png)

  scope :search, ->(search_text) {where(meal_category: search_text)}
```